# color specific placeholder using css

Tags: html, css, placeholder

Hi how i can change color to a specific placeholder?

example i got this:

```
<div class="form-group m-b-15">
<input type="text" id="login" class="form-control form-control-lg no" placeholder="Nº de usuario,Email o cédula" required="" readonly="" value="" autocomplete="off" autofocus="">
</div>
```

and this

```
<div class="form-group m-b-15">
<input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg no" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required="" autocomplete="off" value="">
</div>
```

i just need to change placeholder of the first input text of my form.

i had tried the following code:

```
#login input#text::-webkit-input-placeholder {color:#ff5b57;}
#login input#text::-moz-placeholder          {color:#ff5b57;}
#login input#text:-moz-placeholder           {color:#ff5b57;}
#login input#text:-ms-input-placeholder      {color:#ff5b57;}
```

but is not working, what im doing wrong?

thank you

Comment: `#login input#text` Finds an input element with the ID "text" inside an element with the ID "login". If you want to find a text input **with** the ID "login", your selector is incorrect.

Comment: Do you want all the input element with type text? or only the element input with id login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Select Input id and set placeholder style

```css
    input#login::placeholder {
        color: red;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="form-group m-b-15">
<input type="text" id="login" class="form-control form-control-lg no" placeholder="Nº de usuario,Email o cédula" required="" readonly="" value="" autocomplete="off" autofocus="">
</div>
```

Comment: A couple of general pointers: Don't use `!important` unless absolutely necessary, preferably only when a rule is intended as a global override. A selector containing an ID doesn't require anything else, since the ID is unique, the `input` part of `input#login` doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score -2):

This should be like below

```
#login::-webkit-input-placeholder {color:#ff5b57;}
#login::-moz-placeholder          {color:#ff5b57;}
#login:-ms-input-placeholder      {color:#ff5b57;}
```